# Pig-Latin sentence

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I am trying to create a method that will take a string sentence as an argument, and translate that sentence into pig Latin. I am currently trying to do this all within one method.

I can easily do this for a single word:

```
def pig_latin_word(word)
  vowels = %w(a e i o u)
  word_array = word.split('')
  if vowels.include?(word_array[0])
    word_array.join('')
  else
    until vowels.include?(word_array[0])
      word_array += word_array.shift(1)
    end
    word = word_array.join('')
    "#{word}ay"
  end
end
```

I would now like to do the same thing but have the method take a sentence. This is what I have so far:

```
def pig_latin_sentence(sentence)
  vowels = %w(a e i o u)
  sentence_array  = sentence.split.each_slice(1).map{|a| a.join('')}
  sentence_array.each do |word|
    if vowels.include?(word[0])
      sentence_array.join(' ')
    else
      until vowels.include?(word[0])
        word_array = word.split('')
        word_array += word_array.shift(1)
      end
      p sentence_array.join('ay ')
    end
  end
end
```

I initially was trying to take the sentence and slice it so that I had each word separated. I could then iterate through an array, each word being an element. However, in order for me to perform the `.shift` method, I would have to split each string element again. How can I achieve this?

Also, does anyone have a cleaner way of writing a single word method?

Comment: (1) The sentence method should *use* the word method; this is decomposition of the problem, and is a good idea. (2) The word method should just return `word` if it starts w/ a vowel (although that's not proper pig latin, e.g., "alien" should be "alienay"), e.g., `return word if vowels.include?(word_array[0])` etc. Regarding the sentence method that "does not work"--please describe the failure and what you expect instead to make it a complete question.

Comment: @Dave's right. I confirmed with a friend who grew up on Boara Boara.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Booooooooo! Lol

Comment: @Dave, ethay ewnay ooklay isway, erway, eryvay ecomingbay.

Comment: "is it homework".gsub(/\w+/){|e|"#{e=~/^([^aeiou]+)/i?$'+$&:e}ay"}

Answer (score 2):

As Dave Newton says, let your pig_latin_word handle the words.If something goes wrong with the words, you'll know where to look;  likewise with the sentences.

```
sentence.split.each_slice(1).map{|a| a.join('')}
```

is code from someone who has worked too hard.

```
def pig_latin_sentence(sentence)
  pig_words = sentence.split.map do |word|
    pig_latin_word(word)
  end
  pig_words.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: ...or `sentence.gsub(/\w+/) { |w| pig_latin_word(w) }`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I made for pig latin, it's a little bit shorter!

```
def pig_latin_ified(word)
  index = /[aeiou]/ =~ word
  return word if index == 0
  word_array = word.chars
  final_solution = (word_array + word_array.shift(index) + ["a", "y"]).join("")
end
```